# Typescript : How to resolve 'rxjs/Rx has no exported member 'SubscriptionLike'

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to follow this example here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gxCu5TEmxXE, but when doing `tsc -p`, I get an error. Is there something I need to import?

**ERROR:**

`node_modules/@angular/common/src/location/location.d.ts(1,10): error TS2305: Module '"...functions/node_modules/rxjs/Rx"' has no exported member 'SubscriptionLike'.`

**TS FILE**

```
import "zone.js/dist/zone-node";
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";
import * as express from "express"
import { renderModuleFactory } from "@angular/platform-server"
import * as fs from "fs"

const document = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + "/dist-server/index.html", "utf8");
const AppServerModuleNgFactory = require(__dirname + "/dist-server/main.bundle");

const app = express();
app.get("**", (req, res) => {
    const url = req.path;
    renderModuleFactory(AppServerModuleNgFactory, { document, url }).then(html => {
        res.send(html);
    });
});
exports.post = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

**CONFIG**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es2015",
    "rootDir": ".",
    "outDir": "../functions"
  },
  "files": [
    "index.ts"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Think you should reinstall @angular package, that doesn't exist in my version.

Comment: @rrd just uninstalled and `npm i @angular/platform-server`, same error.

Answer (score 19):

I faced the same issue after following

[Following this tutorial from djamware](https://www.djamware.com/post/59924f9080aca768e4d2b12e/ionic-3-consuming-rest-api-using-new-angular-43-httpclient)

After searching a lot, I have found that Rxjs package that is installed through instructions in this tutorial is not supported with Angular 6.

Angular 6 does not work with RxJS 5.5 but with RxJS 6.

```
npm i rxjs@6
```

Run the above command in cli and that should fix your problem. It did in my case.

Comment: Shouldn't you run `npm i rxjs@6 --save`?

Comment: @dudewad As of npm 5.0.0, installed modules are added as a dependency by default, so the --save option is no longer needed.

Answer (score 4):

I'd bet if you looked in your `package.json` you'd see a lot of `beta` `angular` package versions. You can either downgrade to the [release version](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular/core) or, if for some strange reason you need to keep using the beta version, you can edit that `location.d.ts` file and change the 2 places that `SubcriptionLike` is used in that file to just `Subscription`. Again, this is super hacky, gets wiped out each time you run `npm install` and only should be used if you need to muck around with the `beta` for some reason. Your dependencies in the `package.json` should look kind of like this (though mine is geared for `ionic`):

```
"dependencies": {
  "@angular/cli": "^1.7.3",
  "@angular/common": "^5.2.9",
  "@angular/compiler": "^5.2.9",
  "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.2.9",
  "@angular/core": "^5.2.9",
  "@angular/forms": "^5.2.9",
  "@angular/http": "^5.2.9",
  "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.2.9",
  "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.2.9",
  "@angular/tsc-wrapped": "^4.4.6",
  "@ionic-native/core": "4.4.0",
  "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "4.4.0",
  "@ionic-native/status-bar": "4.4.0",
  "@ionic/pro": "1.0.17",
  "@ionic/storage": "2.1.3",
  "ionic-angular": "3.9.2",
  "ionicons": "3.0.0",
  "rxjs": "^5.5.6",
  "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
  "zone.js": "0.8.18"
}
```

Comment: Ok, downgrading to release solved a few issues, but still stuck with something else, can you have a look at this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49472738/angular-universal-how-to-resolve-missing-names-modules-and-other-weird-things

Answer (score 1):

The latest version for rxjs is 6.9.0 To fix this issue you have to update rxjs package.
run `ng update rxjs`

Comment: 6.9? Current `latest` is https://www.npmjs.com/package/rxjs/v/6.5.5