# Angular Universal : How to resolve missing names, modules and other weird things

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, server-side-rendering

Everything works well in the main app, but trying to serve the bundled SSR produces errors I don't understand. I'll post everything below regarding setup.

There are too many small pieces that just break, everywhere, I hope the process of producing a server side app will improve with time.

Also there are parts of this setup I'm not really confident about as I'm still trying to get the hang of this, any suggestions for improvement will be appreciated, thanks.

**functions : package json**

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "serve": "firebase serve --only functions",
    "shell": "firebase experimental:functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase-admin": "~5.10.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^0.9.0",
    "@angular/animations": "^5.2.9",
    "@angular/cdk": "^5.2.4",
    "@angular/common": "^5.2.9",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.2.9",
    "@angular/core": "^5.2.9",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.2.9",
    "@angular/http": "^5.2.9",
    "@angular/material": "^2.0.0-beta.10",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.2.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.2.9",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^5.2.9",
    "@angular/router": "^5.2.9",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-beta.5",
    "@nguniversal/express-engine": "^5.0.0-beta.7",
    "@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader": "^5.0.0-beta.7",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.74",
    "angularfire2": "^4.0.0-rc0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.0.0-beta",
    "core-js": "^2.5.1",
    "firebase": "^4.3.1",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "jquery-ui": "^1.12.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.5",
    "rxjs": "^5.4.3",
    "scss": "^0.2.4",
    "ts-loader": "^4.1.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.17",
    "express": "^4.15.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^1.7.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.2.9",
    "@angular/language-service": "^4.4.3",
    "@types/bootstrap": "^3.3.36",
    "@types/core-js": "^0.9.46",
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.6.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.3",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.2.12",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.88",
    "angular-universal-express-firebase": "0.0.4",
    "codelyzer": "~3.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^3.6.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "^1.7.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "node-sass": "^4.5.3",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~3.0.4",
    "tslint": "~5.3.2",
    "typescript": "^2.7.2"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

**The server functions**

```
import 'zone.js/dist/zone-node';
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as express from 'express';
import { renderModuleFactory } from '@angular/platform-server';
import * as fs from 'fs';

const document = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/index.html', 'utf8');
const AppServerModuleNgFactory = require(__dirname + '/dist-server/main.bundle');

const app = express();

app.get('**', (req, res) => {
    const url = req.path;
    renderModuleFactory(AppServerModuleNgFactory, { document, url })
        .then(html => {
            res.set('Cache-Control', 'public, max-age=600');
            res.send(html);
        });
});

export let ssrapp = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

**Server TS Config**

```
{
    "compileOnSave": false,
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "../",
        "rootDir": ".",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "declaration": false,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "target": "es5",
        "typeRoots": [
            "node_modules/@types"
        ],
        "lib": [
            "es2016",
            "dom"
        ]
    },
    "files": [
        "index.ts"
    ]
}
```

**I serve with `firebase serve --only functions`**, after serving I get different kind of errors, after fixing, another one will come up.

So far I'm stuck on this.

TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

```
at ...functions/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:5528:146
at ZoneDelegate.invoke (...functions/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-node.js:388:26)
at Object.onInvoke (.../functions/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:4787:33)
at ZoneDelegate.invoke (.../functions/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-node.js:387:32)
at Zone.run (.../functions/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-node.js:138:43)
at NgZone.run (.../functions/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:4604:69)
at PlatformRef.bootstrapModuleFactory (.../functions/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:5527:23)
at Object.renderModuleFactory (.../functions/node_modules/@angular/platform-server/bundles/platform-server.umd.js:1815:39)
at .../functions/index.js:13:23
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (.../functions/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
```

**THE ORIGIN APP:**

**PACKAGE JSON**

```
{
  "name": "my app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --host 0.0.0.0",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.2.9",
    "@angular/cdk": "^2.0.0-beta.10",
    "@angular/common": "^5.2.9",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.2.9",
    "@angular/core": "^5.2.9",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.2.9",
    "@angular/http": "^5.2.9",
    "@angular/material": "^2.0.0-beta.10",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.2.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.2.9",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^5.2.9",
    "@angular/router": "^5.2.9",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-beta.5",
    "@nguniversal/express-engine": "^5.0.0-beta.7",
    "@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader": "^5.0.0-beta.7",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.74",
    "angularfire2": "^4.0.0-rc0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.0.0-beta",
    "core-js": "^2.5.1",
    "firebase": "^4.3.1",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "jquery-ui": "^1.12.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.5",
    "rxjs": "^5.4.3",
    "scss": "^0.2.4",
    "ts-loader": "^4.1.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.17"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^1.7.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.2.9",
    "@angular/language-service": "^4.4.3",
    "@types/bootstrap": "^3.3.36",
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.6.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.3",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.2.12",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.88",
    "angular-universal-express-firebase": "0.0.4",
    "codelyzer": "~3.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "^1.7.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "node-sass": "^4.5.3",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~3.0.4",
    "tslint": "~5.3.2",
    "typescript": "^2.6.2"
  }
}
```

**TSCONFIG**

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2016",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

**TSCONFIG.SERVER.JSON**

```
{
    "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "../out/-tsc/app",
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "types": []
    },
    "exclude": [
        "test.ts",
        "**/*.spec.ts"
    ],
    "angularCompileOptions": {
        "entryModule": "app/app.server.module#AppServerModule"
    }
}
```

**APP.SERVER.MODULE.TS**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { ServerModule } from '@angular/platform-server';

import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
    imports: [AppModule, ServerModule],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppServerModule { }
```

**APP.MODULE.TS**

```
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AngularFireModule } from 'angularfire2';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';
import { AngularFireDatabaseModule } from 'angularfire2/database';
import { AngularFireAuthModule } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import { DataService } from './dataservice';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { Location, LocationStrategy, PathLocationStrategy } from '@angular/common';
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import {
  MdDialog, MaterialModule, MdButtonModule, MdCardModule, MdToolbarModule, MdInputModule,
  MdMenuModule, MdIconModule, MdProgressBarModule, MdRadioModule, MdDialogModule, MdSelectModule, MdTabsModule,
  MdSnackBarModule, MdProgressSpinnerModule, MdTooltipModule
} from '@angular/material';

import { PostsUtilComponent } from './utils/postsUtil';
import { FeaturesComponent } from './features/features.component';
import { MediaPlayerService } from './utils/mediaPlayerService';
import { HomeUtils } from './home/homeUtils';
import { DownloadComponent } from './download/download.component';
import { PostComponent } from './post/post.component';
import { NodesComponent } from './utils/nodes';
import { PostFactory } from './utils/postFactory';
import { TestServerFunctionComponent } from './utils/testServerFunction';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'projects', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'features', component: FeaturesComponent },
  { path: 'download', component: DownloadComponent },
  { path: 'post', component: PostComponent },

];
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    BrowserModule.withServerTransition({ appId: 'serverside' }),
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes),
    NgbModule.forRoot(),
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase),
    AngularFireDatabaseModule,
    AngularFireAuthModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MdDialogModule,
    MdButtonModule,
    MdCardModule,
    MdMenuModule,
    MdToolbarModule,
    MdIconModule,
    MdProgressBarModule,
    MdInputModule,
    MdRadioModule,
    MdSelectModule,
    MdTabsModule,
    MdSnackBarModule,
    MdProgressSpinnerModule,
    MdTooltipModule
  ],
  providers: [DataService, PostsUtilComponent, NodesComponent, PostFactory, MediaPlayerService,
    HomeUtils, TestServerFunctionComponent],
  declarations: [AppComponent, HomeComponent, FeaturesComponent, DownloadComponent, PostComponent],
  entryComponents: [],
  schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**MAIN.TS**

```
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';
import 'hammerjs';

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

**MAIN.SERVER.TS**

```
export { AppServerModule } from './app/app.server.module';
```

Comment: Do you have lazy loaded modules?

Answer (score 2):

Solutions:

1. use npm run build --prod --aot
2. There may be a name variable in your component but you are not initialized any value to it ( eg: public name: any = "title";)

Comment: --aot is on by default.

Comment: @Relm That actually depends on the version they are running, it hasn't always been on by default, and since they are running an older version of @angular/materials(still using md instead of mat), they might not have aot by default

Comment: @JooBeck, my comment is in context of this question.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is the "undefined error" you are getting is caused, because on the server you can't use the browser objects (window, document, navigator). 
See: https://github.com/angular/universal
You could try the following:

- In your AppModule you are including the BrowserAnimationsModule. Remove this Module.
- In the ServerModule include the NoopAnimationsModule. (So you don't
  get errors because your animations are missing)
- Create a new BrowserModule which includes the BrowserAnimationsModule
  and the AppModule. The BrowserModule should also bootstrap the
  AppComponent.
- In your main.ts bootstrap the new BrowserModule.

I hope this helps you resolve your issue.
These steps are also described here: [Need BrowserAnimationsModule in Angular but gives error in Universal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44330537/need-browseranimationsmodule-in-angular-but-gives-error-in-universal)

Since you also asked how to resolve "weird" issues with SSR in general. One tip I can give is to try and remove(comment out) modules and components to find out which part of the application is causing an issue. Thats how I resolved most of the issues, while I was converting a project to Universal.